# Perform filters in datagrid

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have excel data pulled into datagridview. Using SQL commands or any other commands in C#.NET is it possible to perform filters and display the filtered data?

Comment: Did you try it first?

Comment: Yes, I loaded the excel data into datagrid. Now wondering how can I perform filters.

Comment: There is many way of doing that: filtering rows, creating filtered data source, hiding/unhiding rows and so on, so any solution suits you?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can filter your data table easily with the help of c# syntax like, dtData.Select("ColName='hisham'");